# What if the only references are not available in English?

Tags: discussion, references

Should we allow the answer too? Traditional cures tend to be written in local language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that we should allow such references. My logic is similar to [what I presented in another answer](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/165) about allowing references that are only fully accessible via library access or paywall. If the best, most relevant research is only available in another language and the person writing an answer is able to access it (i.e. knows the language), this should be fair game to serve as a reference on this site. The guidelines I would suggest:

- If you *don’t* know the language, I think it’s generally not wise to use this as a reference just because someone else said that the reference says XYZ. People mis-represent references, and if the primary source is not available to you (because you don’t know the language), it’s not a good source for your answer.
- If you *do* know the language, consider quoting the relevant portions and providing your own translation for the benefit of the reader who likely doesn’t.